# Refactor Typescript class into two functions

Tags: node.js, typescript, refactoring

I have a project in Node JS and Typescript in which I have a file with a class that I use to check that a directory exists and create another. To the method I pass two parameters, the main directory ('src/out') and a string with which to create the following directory ('api').

This is my class, the `dir` variable ('src / out') and the `api` variable ('api'):

```
export class createDir {
    checkExistsOrCreate(dir: string, api: any) {
        let dire = `${dir}${api}`;
        if (!fs.existsSync(dir)){
            fs.mkdirSync(dir);
        }
        if (fs.existsSync(dire)) {
            rimraf.sync(dire);
            fs.mkdirSync(dire);
        }else {
            fs.mkdirSync(dire);
        }
        return dire;
    }
}
```

What I want to do is create two functions: the first one I pass the main directory ('src / out') and it checks if it exists. And the second creates the directories, if the principal does not exist, it creates the principal directory and the api directory ('src / out / api') and if the principal exists it will only create the '/ api' directory.

My **problem** is that I don't know how to separate both functions and how to tell the second if the main directory exists or not.

This is the first function that only checks that the directory that reaches it exists:

```
export class exists {
    exitsDir(dir: string) {
        if (!fs.existsSync(dir)){
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the class from which I call the directory check and pass the directory to check:

```
class UtilsController {

    public async utilsDir () {

        try {
            let checkDir = new exists();
            await checkDir.exitsDir('src/out');         
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of classes that are not really needed but this should work:

```js
class UtilsController {
    public utilsDir(): Promise<boolean> {
        try {
            const checkDir = new exists();
            return checkDir.exitsDir('src/out');         
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
}

const test = async () => {
    const utilsController = new UtilsController();
    const exists = await utilsController.utilsDir();
    console.log(exists);
};
```

Comment: I think I have not explained myself well, this is what I want to achieve: 1) from ``UtilsController`` I call exists and pass it the directory that I want to check ('scr / out'), 2) exists returns ``false`` if it does not exist or ``true`` if it exists

Comment: 3) if it does not exist, the ``createDir`` function is called (it is not done yet) passing it the ``dir`` and ``api`` variables and the directory 'src/out' (``dir`` variable) and the directory inside out '/api' (variable ``api``). 4) If the 'src/out' directory exists, the ``createDir`` function is called passing it only the ``api`` variable to create only the 'api' directory (``api`` variable)

Comment: The variables: ''dir = 'src/out''' and ''api = 'api1'''. I do not know if I understand what I want to achieve but I am not able to know from ``UtilsController`` if the directory exists or not.

Comment: I'm very confused by your last feedback and have some questions: (1) Why would you want to implement some functionality that the buuld-in function `mkdir` already provides? (2) Why do you use some many classes without any functionality in the first place? (3) Why would in my example the line `const exists = await utilsController.utilsDir();` not return the boolean that you wanted to have to know if a directory exists?

Answer (score 1):

Actually the [mkdir](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fspromises_mkdir_path_options) function can handle your use case automatically when using the `recursive` option.

```js
const fs = require('fs');
fs.mkdirSync('main/sub', {recursive: true});
```

Comment: I don't know what the recursive option is. I've never seen it. To the function I already passed the directory when calling it from another class, so the function that checks if it exists already receives a variable with the directory. What I don't know is how to tell the function that creates it if the directory exists or not.

Comment: The `mkdir` documentation I linked in my feedback explains the `recursive` option and you can try to run my example.

Comment: I have updated the question with the function that checks if the directory exists, what I want now is to know how to return true or false to the function that creates the file to know if I have to create it or not

Comment: I think your original question on how to create subdirectories can be solved the easiest by just using `mkdir` with the `recursive` option. If you want to implement the logic manually and you (for whatever reason) also want to keep the class definitions you would need to instantiate an `exists` object and invoke the `exitsDir` function.